# Override URL and Authentication configuration of Spring Cloud Feign client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to leverage Spring Cloud Feign client for declaring rest endpoints(third-party-endpoints) which will be called based on the request that my controller receives.

I have declared a feign client interface like:

```
    @FeignClient(name = "my-client", url = "https://abc.xyz.com", configuration = MyClientConfiguration.class)
    public interface MyFeignClient{
}
```

**MyClientConfiguration** is an unannotated feign configuration class just exposing **BasicAuthRequestInterceptor** bean preconfigured with some credential.

```
public class MyClientConfiguration {
   
    @Bean
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor(){
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("USERID","PWD");
    }

}
```

So, what I have right now is a preconfigured feign client.

I am not sure how do I deal with the requirement that asks for being able to define/override the feign configuration with the **url** and **credentials** received in the body of different POST request.

So its not about overriding the feign configuration via properties file(like other somewhat similar SO questions), but instead being able to configure the feign client on the fly based on the **url** and **credentials** received in the body of the incoming requests.

I am aware of ways to do it with WebClient and looking for something similar to what WebClient provides via its **uri** and **headers** methods. Webclient allows us to override the **webClient** bean configuration with different **uri** and different auth credentials,

```
        webClient
                .put()
                .uri("base-uri", uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/rest").path("/api").path("/2").path("/issue").path("/" + id).build())
                .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.setBasicAuth("decrypted-username", "decrypted-pwd");
                })
```

Does Spring Cloud Feign provide any such facility where it is possible to have a generic configuration yet allowing to override those configurations at runtime?

**EDIT 1 : START**

The closest I got to is implementing via the feign's builder pattern :

```
    MyFeignClient myFeignClient = Feign.builder()
            .contract(new SpringMvcContract())
            .requestInterceptor(new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("decrypted-username", "decrypted-pwd")
            .target(MyFeignClient.class, myRequestDTO.getBaseUrl());
```

I was challenged with an exception because I didn't specify which Contract to use. It was using the Default Contract.I then changed to SpringMvcContract as the annotation that I am using are the Spring MVC ones and not feign's default.

Getting DecodeException as of now. Trying to fix it. Will post update when done.

**EDIT 1 : END**

**EDIT 2 : START**

I was finally able to get this working. I figured out that the **feign-gson** does a great job at deserialization with minimal configuration.
My final feign configuration with the Decoder in place looks like :

```
MyFeignClient myFeignClient = Feign.builder()
                .contract(new SpringMvcContract())
                .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                .requestInterceptor(new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("decrypted-username", "decrypted-pwd")
                        .target(MyFeignClient.class, myRequestDTO.getBaseUrl());
```

**EDIT 2 : END**

Comment: Can this solution deal with multiples tokens expiration time? I mean, imagine you generate your first auth token for the first request, so then generate a second one. If you try to authenticate the first one again, will it verify the expiration time or always will do the auth process?